# SunCertPathBuilderException when running HonoExampleApplication

Tags: eclipse-hono

I was following the steps in https://www.eclipse.org/hono/docs/dev-guide/java_client_consumer/ to start the example Hono client.
From the hono-client-examples folder I ran this command -

```
    mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=org.eclipse.hono.vertx.example.HonoExampleApplication
```

But I get an error that it can't connect to AMQP 1.0 container... Failed to create an SSL connection.
The log is here - [https://docdro.id/GOlMORV]
Please let know how to fix this.

**updated with more details**

This is the output from minikube start

C:\WINDOWS\system32>minikube start --cpus 2 --memory 4192
* minikube v1.12.3 on Microsoft Windows 10 Home Single Language 10.0.18363 Build 18363
* Using the virtualbox driver based on existing profile
* Starting control plane node minikube in cluster minikube
* Updating the running virtualbox "minikube" VM ...
* Found network options:
  - NO_PROXY=192.168.99.100,192.168.99.108
  - no_proxy=192.168.99.100,192.168.99.108
* Preparing Kubernetes v1.18.3 on Docker 19.03.12 ...
  - env NO_PROXY=192.168.99.100,192.168.99.108
* Verifying Kubernetes components...
* Enabled addons: default-storageclass, storage-provisioner
* Done! kubectl is now configured to use "minikube"

and the output from minikube tunnel is here -

Status:
        machine: minikube
        pid: 11672
        route: 10.96.0.0/12 -> 192.168.99.106
        minikube: Running
        services: [eclipse-hono-adapter-amqp-vertx, eclipse-hono-adapter-http-vertx, eclipse-hono-adapter-mqtt-vertx, eclipse-hono-dispatch-router-ext, eclipse-hono-service-device-registry-ext]
    errors:
                minikube: no errors
                router: no errors
                loadbalancer emulator: no errors

Comment: what Hono instance are your trying to connect to? If you are not connecting to an instance running on localhost then you need to provide the host and port that you want to connect to, e.g. `mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=org.eclipse.hono.vertx.example.HonoExampleApplication -Dconsumer.host=192.168.99.100 -Dconsumer.port=15671`

Comment: How do I find out which is the ipaddress and port of the hono instance? I have updated the ticket with more details. I tried with the address:port from echo $DOCKER_HOST command, I tried with the ip address from minikube start - 192.168.99.106 , it was the same error. Now I edited the file honoexampleconstants with 192.168.99.100 as consumer host and 15671 as port , there is no certificate error anymore but it still cannot connect o the AMQP network. here is the latest log - https://docdro.id/oRQTUx2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you are running Hono on a local minikube cluster with `minikube tunnel` running, you can determine the IP address and port of Hono's northbound API as follows (replace `hono` with the namespace that you have installed Hono to):

```sh
kubectl get service -n hono
```

The output should look something like

```
NAME                               TYPE           CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP      PORT(S)                           AGE
hono-adapter-http-vertx            LoadBalancer   10.97.191.104    10.97.191.104    8080:30080/TCP,8443:30443/TCP     54s
hono-adapter-mqtt-vertx            LoadBalancer   10.101.44.17     10.101.44.17     1883:31883/TCP,8883:30883/TCP     54s
hono-artemis                       ClusterIP      10.98.143.229    <none>           5671/TCP                          54s
hono-dispatch-router               ClusterIP      10.98.227.78     <none>           5673/TCP                          54s
hono-dispatch-router-ext           LoadBalancer   10.106.80.60     10.106.80.60     15671:30671/TCP,15672:30672/TCP   54s
hono-service-auth                  ClusterIP      10.96.90.255     <none>           5671/TCP                          54s
hono-service-device-registry       ClusterIP      10.96.7.34       <none>           5671/TCP,8443/TCP                 54s
hono-service-device-registry-ext   LoadBalancer   10.106.247.124   10.106.247.124   28080:31080/TCP,28443:31443/TCP   54s
kubernetes                         ClusterIP      10.96.0.1        <none>           443/TCP                           129d
```

The northbound API's IP address is the one listed for the `hono-dispatch-router-ext` in column *EXTERNAL-IP*. The TLS protected port (AMQPS) is 15671.